# jump to top of div once expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="newsPara">
    Initial copy here   
    <a href="#" class="readmore">Read more&raquo; </a>
        <ul class="accordianUl" style="display: none">
            <li>
            content hidden here
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when a user clicks the read more the sub ul expands. using the following code

```
$('#menu li a').click(function () {
    $('#menu li a').show();
    $(this).hide();
    var checkElement = $(this).next('ul');
    if (checkElement.is(':visible')) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkElement.is(':visible')) {
        $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).parent('.accordianUl').position().top }, 'slow'); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

I want once the sub ul has expanded to jump to the top of it ive tried this

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).parent('.accordianUl').position().top }, 'slow');
```

but it doesnt seem to work

can anyone help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `$(this).parent()` is returning null as it has not got an accordianUl in it. $(this) refers to the current element calling the function,  see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/wfeWW/

```
$('#menu li a').click(function () {
  $('#menu li a').show();
  $(this).hide();
  $this = $(this);     //KEEP THAT ELEMENT JUST INCASE
  console.log($this);    //IT IS THE LI > A
  var checkElement = $(this).next('ul');
  if (checkElement.is(':visible')) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!checkElement.is(':visible')) {
    $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: checkElement.position().top }, 'slow'); 
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, can you provide more details than "that doesnt work" ? works fine in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/wfeWW/

Comment: you can actually see the page here http://eatg.anytimeafter9.co.uk/about-step-up/testimonials

Comment: im lost on that page and not too bothered looking for your problem on it. lol. effort is relative bro.